# Create function for an update

Tags: mysql

I used a column 'Title' in a table 'incident'. This column contains some information .Among this information, three character that indicates the region .these three character are usually found after ('on', ':'). I want to execute a function (mysql) which allows: 1) if the three character taken from the 'Title' column, which are located after 'on', are( kef or bej or jen) so the result will be stored in a column 'test' in the same table. 2) if the first is not achieved then takes the three character which are located after ':' and stored in a column 'test1' in the same table.
there is the code that i used :

```
delimiter |
CREATE FUNCTION METTER5 (s VARCHAR(2000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(10000)
DETERMINISTIC
   BEGIN
         DECLARE open  INT;
           DECLARE close  INT;
           DECLARE someLimit  INT;
           DECLARE str  VARCHAR(2000);
           DECLARE str1  VARCHAR(2000);
            DECLARE str2  VARCHAR(2000);
            DECLARE str3  VARCHAR(2000);
           DECLARE toFind  VARCHAR(2000);
           DECLARE co VARCHAR(2000);
           SET co='';
           SET open = 1;
           SET close = 1;
           SET toFind = s ;
           SET someLimit =100;
           SET str='';
           SET str1='';
           SET str2='';
         /* SET tofind=concat(tofind,'sur','');*/
 SET str =substring(trim(substring_index(s,'sur',-1)),1,3);           
 SET str1 =substring(trim(substring_index(s,'du',-1)),1,3);
 SET str2 =substring(trim(substring_index(s,':',-1)),1,3);

IF  (str in ('ZAG','TUN','TOZ','TAT','SOS','SIL','SFX','SBO','RNC','BAR','BEJ','BIZ','BSC','GAB','GAF','JEN','KAI','KAS','KEB','KEF','MAH','MED','MON','NAB')) =1 THEN set co = str ;
ELSE IF ((str not in ('ZAG','TUN','TOZ','TAT','SOS','SIL','SFX','SBO','RNC','BAR','BEJ','BIZ','BSC','GAB','GAF','JEN','KAI','KAS','KEB','KEF','MAH','MED','MON','NAB')) and (str1 in ('ZAG','TUN','TOZ','TAT','SOS','SIL','SFX','SBO','RNC','BAR','BEJ','BIZ','BSC','GAB','GAF','JEN','KAI','KAS','KEB','KEF','MAH','MED','MON','NAB')))=1 THEN set co = str1 ;
ELSE IF ((str1 not in ('ZAG','TUN','TOZ','TAT','SOS','SIL','SFX','SBO','RNC','BAR','BEJ','BIZ','BSC','GAB','GAF','JEN','KAI','KAS','KEB','KEF','MAH','MED','MON','NAB'))and (str2 in ('ZAG','TUN','TOZ','TAT','SOS','SIL','SFX','SBO','RNC','BAR','BEJ','BIZ','BSC','GAB','GAF','JEN','KAI','KAS','KEB','KEF','MAH','MED','MON','NAB')))=1 THEN SET co = str2 ;
ELSE set co = '1' ; 
END IF;
END IF;
END IF;
           return co;
   END |
 delimiter;
```

and there is the query that i used :

```
update incident set test =METTER5 (Title) WHERE  Affected_CI like 'other ci' and open_time between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-30'
```

but after the running , there is the problem  : Unknown column 'description' in 'field list'

thanks.

Comment: From where you are getting `description` in this line `SET str1 =substring(trim(substring_index(description,'du',-1)),1,3);  ` ? Did you mean `s` since its in `in` param

Comment: description is a colomn where the information is stocked

Comment: Ok , so now how your function knows about that, I do not see either you are passing that into the function or using some query to retrieve it inside the function.

Comment: execuse me there is the right query :update incident set test =METTER5 (description) WHERE  Affected_CI like 'other ci' and open_time between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-30'

Comment: By query i meant inside the function `METTER5` , so here it is when you call `METTER5 (description)` the `description` is the input and you have the function signature `CREATE FUNCTION METTER6(s VARCHAR(2000))` So inside the function you can not use `description` you need to use `s` since its the argument name.

Comment: i changed the query to : update incident set test =METTER6 (description) WHERE Affected_CI like 'other ci' and open_time between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-30'    but no result

Comment: You have to change all `SET str1 =substring(trim(substring_index(description,'du',-1)),1,3);` lines inside to function to `SET str1 =substring(trim(substring_index(s,'du',-1)),1,3); `

Comment: I changed str1 and and I changed something in the code.  It takes the condition 1 'str'. But the problem is that it takes neither condition ' str1 'or' str2 '.